# How to track users in Rails using Google Analytics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-analytics

I am using the following google analytics code to track users in my Ruby on Rails 4 app

```
    // ga('create', 'UA-1234567-1', 'auto');
    ga('create', 'UA-1234567-1', 'auto', { 'userId': <%= current_user.id %> });
    // ga('set', '&uid', <%= current_user.id %>); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

but I am getting the error

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

for the line

```
ga('create', 'UA-1234567-1', 'auto', { 'userId': <%= current_user.id %> });
```

I am following this thread [How do I set USER_ID in Google Universal Analytics tracking code in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25041519/how-do-i-set-user-id-in-google-universal-analytics-tracking-code-in-rails) and official doc https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id but not sure what is going wrong as it is almost same code.

Answer (score 1):

Add a check condition for logged_in user only -

```
<% if current_user.present? %>
 <script>
  //analytics stuffs

   ga('create', 'UA-1234567-1', 'auto', { 'userId': <%= current_user.id %> }); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
   ga('send', 'pageview');
 </script>
<% end %>
```

Or

```
 <script>
  //analytics stuffs

   ga('create', 'UA-1234567-1', 'auto', { 'userId': <%= current_user.present? ? current_user.id : nil %> }); // Set the user ID using signed-in user_id.
   ga('send', 'pageview');
 </script>
```

Comment: But then the code won't run for anonymous users! I can run if else though.

Comment: Hmm anonymous users does't contain `user_id` from database. :(

Comment: You can use it like this 
`ga('create', 'UA-1234567-1', 'auto', { 'userId': <%= current_user.present? ? current_user.id : nil %> });` Hope this can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend sending a zero in the case of an anonymous user since this condition will never exist in your production database. That way you can still track those users if you ever decide you need to.

If you're fine doing that then this should do the trick:

```
ga('create', 'UA-1234567-1', 'auto', {'userId': <%= user_signed_in? ? current_user.id : 0 %>})
```

Here's a link to the documentation for `user_signed_in?` https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers